# Browser Time Based CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use different stylesheets pending on the time of day. But the time only works sometimes.

```
<script>

function getStylesheet() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
      if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11.30) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='one.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (11.30 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 12) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='two.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (12 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 13) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='three.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
if (13.30 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 14) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='four.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
if (14 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 15) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='six.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
if (15.30 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='seven.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
}

getStylesheet();

</script>
```

I'm only getting the stylesheets working in between 2.00pm & 4.00pm

Comment: `getHours` returns the hours as an integer - so comparing that against values such as `11.30` makes really rather little sense.

Comment: Unless the formatting you want to apply is _massively_ different (in terms of what is actually different in the CSS, not optical result), this should probably rather be done using _one_ stylesheet to begin with. Add a class to the `html` element dynamically, based on the time, and then use that class in your stylesheet to format the descendants of the html element differently.

Comment: getHours() returns a specific hour (you can [try it yourself here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours)). There are no circumstances under which it will return (for example) `11.30`. You don't have that level of precision. So right now, "two.css" and "four.css" and "seven.css" will never ever be used, for instance (so I don't know how you can claim it works up to 4pm - it doesn't). Demo (adjusted slightly to show a test case for each possible relevant input value): https://jsfiddle.net/k5w2ah06/ .

Comment: In conclusion, you'd need to request the minutes as well and check those at the same time. And hrs/minutes are not fractions (half past 11 != 11.3). Also, what is supposed to happen before 11am and after 4pm? Or between 1300 and 1330, or between 1500 and 1530? Does it just revert to no stylesheet? Any reason there's no "five.css"? And as misorude says, doing this with separate stylesheets and document.write is likely to be highly suboptimal (as is not using `elseif`). I get the sense you haven't really thought this through, or tested it much either.

Comment: @ADyson I was using <noscript><link href="all.css" rel="stylesheet"></noscript>
to revert to no stylesheet. Could you please tell me how minutes can also be checked? It's very hard for me to figure out. And 4pm only worked when that was the only if statement

Comment: Thanks heaps for all your support!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes would be what you'd need.

Comment: Ps. Your all.css there  would only work if the browser didn't support JavaScript at all or the user has turned it off (which these days would be highly unlikely). I meant what would you do if the time was outside the ones you had listed in the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no value like 13.30. Date.getHours can be 11 or 12.

This one working well and looks cleaner and working only with hours.

```
function getStylesheet () {
  let currHour =  new Date().getHours()
  let styleFile = 'one.css'

  if (currHour >= 11) styleFile = 'one.css'
  if (currHour >= 12) styleFile = 'two.css'
  if (currHour >= 13) styleFile = 'three.css'
  if (currHour >= 14) styleFile = 'four.css'
  if (currHour >= 15) styleFile = 'six.css'
  if (currHour >= 16) styleFile = 'seven.css'

  document.write(
     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${styleFile}" type="text/css">`
  );
}
```

If you want to count minutes as well:

```
function getStylesheet() {
    let now = new Date();
    let currMins = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes();

    let styleFile = 'one.css';

    //  now min  >=  h  * 60  + min
    if (currMins >= (11 * 60) + 30) styleFile = 'one.css';
    if (currMins >= (12 * 60)) styleFile = 'two.css';
    if (currMins >= (13 * 60)) styleFile = 'three.css';
    if (currMins >= (14 * 60)) styleFile = 'four.css';
    if (currMins >= (15 * 60)) styleFile = 'six.css';
    if (currMins >= (16 * 60)) styleFile = 'seven.css';

    document.write(
        currMins, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${styleFile}" type="text/css">`
    );
}
```

But I'd recommend this:

```
document.body.setAttribute('hour', new Date().getHours())
```

So now you can use it in your selector like:

```
body[hour=1] { background: #001112 }
body[hour=2] { background: #002244 }
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner better code. Is there any way to check hours & minutes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition checking is wrong. You are grabbing only hour and checking for minutes.

For example if the time is 11.45 then your currentTime will have value 11 so your second condition can't be checked.